# TEA Encryption in JAVA

Tags: java, encryption

I want to encrypt 4 number, but so far only 2 of them are being encrypted. I have tried placing the `encrypt` method into the loop but it doesnt encrypt and decrypt more than 2 number. Anyone is able to help on this?

```
public class TEA {

    private static int delta = 0x9E3779B9; /* a key schedule constant */

    private static int[] key = { 78945677, 87678687, 234234, 234234 };

    public void encrypt(int[] v, int[] k) {

        int v0 = v[0], v1 = v[1], sum = 0, n = 32;
        int k0 = k[0], k1 = k[1], k2 = k[2], k3 = k[3]; /* cache key */
        while (n-- > 0) {
            sum += delta;
            v0 += ((v1 << 4) + k0) ^ (v1 + sum) ^ ((v1 >>> 5) + k1);
            v1 += ((v0 << 4) + k2) ^ (v0 + sum) ^ ((v0 >>> 5) + k3);
        }
        v[0] = v0;
        v[1] = v1;
        System.out.println(v0 + "," + v1);

    }

    public void decrypt(int[] v, int[] k) {
        int v0 = v[0], v1 = v[1], sum = 0xC6EF3720, n = 32; /* set up */
        int k0 = k[0], k1 = k[1], k2 = k[2], k3 = k[3]; /* cache key */
        while (n-- > 0) {
            v1 -= ((v0 << 4) + k2) ^ (v0 + sum) ^ ((v0 >>> 5) + k3);
            v0 -= ((v1 << 4) + k0) ^ (v1 + sum) ^ ((v1 >>> 5) + k1);
            sum -= delta;
        }
        v[0] = v0;
        v[1] = v1;

        System.out.println(v0 + "," + v1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        TEA tea = new TEA();
        int n = 0;
        int cc[] = new int[100];

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter 4 number to encrypt: ");
            n = input.nextInt();
            cc[i] = n;

        }

        tea.encrypt(cc, key);
        tea.decrypt(cc, key);

    }

}
```

Comment: You don't using `v[2]` and `v[3]` in your code and these nubers leaves unchanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` work with first two elements.

So you have to either shift arrays in a calling method in cycle, or introduce a cycle over consecutive pairs in encrypt/decrypt method like

```
for (int idx = 0; idx < v.length; idx *= 2)
{
    int v0 = v[idx], v1 = v[idx + 1], sum = 0, n = 32;
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**
According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm) example, the method expects only two integers (and not any length array). You need pass your numbers by pairs, like

```
for (int idx = 0; idx < 4; idx =* 2)
{
    int[] tmp = {cc[idx], cc[idx + 1};
    tea.encrypt(tmp, key);
    cc[idx] = tmp[0];
    cc[idx + 1] = tmp[1];
}
```

As a result, for each pair of integers you will receive another pair of integers but encrypted.

Comment: is that possible to achieve the same thing without changing the codes in encryption and decryption ?

Comment: Then you have to always pass array of two integers into encrypt, and select these two integers in main(). Wiki example (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm) tells the method works only for two integers, and not for any length array. I'll update the unswer

Comment: yup i converted that into java. But C is using unsigned integer where as java doesnt have it

Comment: Have a little issue here, it doesnt stop after 4 number has been input. idx <4